# Can someone help me understand setting up the derivative to this parametric equation.

Tags: calculus

$x = 2\sin(1+3t)$ and 
$y = 2t^3$

I understand to get the derivative for this you would set $\frac{dy}{dt}$ divided by $\frac{dx}{dt}$. I am trying to understand the reasoning for this, I know it's becuase of the chain rule. I am having trouble setting it up as a composition function. So could someone explain how I would do that?

Comment: The chain rule is already a composition function, no?

Comment: if you are searching for $$\frac{dy}{dx}$$ you will need $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy}{dt}\cdot \frac{dt}{dx}$$

Comment: Yes I understand this. In order to use chain rule we must have a function composition function, correct? So how do i set my x and y up so its a composition function , which i can then use the chain rule on. Im just trying to visualize the process so I can have the intuition behind this.

Answer (score 0):

For this problem, you could solve the first equation for $t$ with $t = \frac{Arcsin(x/2) - 1}{3}$.  Then plug that solution for $t$ into the second equation to have $y$ as a composite function of $x$.

However, the formula given by Dr. Graubner handles situations where this is not possible.